# $cookies.putObject not working in angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I upgraded from angular 1.2 (original code) more recently to 1.3 (which broke the cookies) to 1.4 as of today ($cookieStore is now deprecated infavor of $cookies)

I added a line `$cookies.putObject('user', user);` but it isn't saved to cookies (i verified in chrome resources tab)

```
        /**
         * Authenticate user
         *
         * @param  {Object}   user     - login info
         * @param  {Function} callback - optional
         * @return {Promise}
         */
        login: function (user, callback) {
            var cb = callback || angular.noop;

            return Session.save({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }, function (user) {
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                $cookies.putObject('user', user); //does not save

                return cb();
            }, function (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }).$promise;
        },
```

I put a breakpoint right after the `$cookies.putObject` and I get `undefined` when I try `$cookies.getObject('user')` in chrome console.

This is an issue because now whenever I refresh the page, I lose the logged in user. The `Auth.js` service has this line up front:

```
    // Get currentUser from cookie
    $rootScope.currentUser = $cookies.getObject('user') || null;
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you've verified that Session.save is passing back the user properly and not passing back undefined?

function (user) {
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                $cookies.putObject('user', user); //does not save

                return cb();
            }

Comment: yup. i definitely have a user object. But I think I figured out my problem...I see that my object is too big to fit in a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed angular puts a warning in console...which I missed. My object is over the cookie size limit of 4093. Mine was 4207.

So what I did was instead save the `userId` to the cookie...which allows all my checks for a logged in user to work, and update the code to fetch the logged in user object from the server.

I was originally putting the user object in `localStorage` but that became a management nightmare -- whenever a user is updated (which can happen in multiple places across the app)... I would have to refresh the `localStorage`.

Instead I do this on every page refresh:

```
    // Get currentUser from cookie
    $rootScope.currentUser = $cookies.get('userId');

    User.get().$promise
        .then(function(user){
            $rootScope.currentUser = user._id && user || null;
        });
```

Comment: This is the user service module :)